# Clone Git repo with Bash script

Tags: git

I'm diving into the world of Git and my first task is to automate our build process.  I'm using Bash since that's what I'm familiar with and it seems to do what I need.

Before I can build my code, I need to clone the latest version of the repo to my PC.

I seem to have a catch 22.  I want to clone a repo from a Bash script that would be part of the repo I'm trying to clone.

I want my build/bash script to be under source control along with everything else... But I'd also like a one command operation.

How do others tackle this problem?  I'm most familiar with ClearCase so Git is taking some getting used to.

Comment: Don't store your deployment scripts in the same repo as the code its deploying, that makes no sense.

Comment: It's a catch 22 because cloning a repository is an action, by definition, *external* to a repository. The script the clones the repository, at least, must be deployed independently of the rest of the build system. Ideally, the entire build system lives outside the repository; it takes as *input* a repository containing software to build.

Comment: So what I use is a continuous integration service (travis-ci in my case) listening to pushes on my master branch on github. The push triggers a build that clones the repo into the travis environment - from there I have access to my deploy scripts and if the build passes, the deploy scripts are triggered.

Comment: Can you show some code, please?

Comment: If I don't make the build script part of the repo (or this repo for that matter), how would I go about putting the script under source control?  Allowing people to make changes to 'tools' that generate production software all willy nilly gives me heart burn.

I guess I could place the build script in another repo, but then project files are scattered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git `clone` is analogous to ClearCase `mkview` in that it creates a new working folder that serves as the main way to interact with files in the repository. If you were writing this script for ClearCase, would you really start by having it create a new ClearCase view? If you did, you'd have the same catch-22 situation.

The common approach is to assume that the `clone` operation was done as part of one-time setup of this build system, and the script already has access to the working folder. The Git commands you'd be more interested in are `clean`,  `checkout`, `fetch`,  `pull`, and `reset --hard`. There's overlap between Git commands, so you won't need all of these. Obviously the choice of Git commands and the options you'd call them with depends on what you want you want your script to do.

Done that way, there's no problem keeping the script in the repository, except you will wind up versioning it in the same branch(es) as the code you're building. This isn't necessarily bad, but is different from what would (usually) happen in ClearCase.

Comment: Essentially I could do a `git checkout branch_name` or `git checkout master` to sync my local repo up with the latest changes on each branch? @gatkin

Comment: Essentially. I'm not going to write your script, but `git fetch; git checkout master; git reset --hard origin/master`  should get you started.